# Import Stylus Variable Another File Vue Vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vite, stylus

For the following stylus variables file that is loaded globally using the `preprocessorOptions` in my vite.config file:

```
// variables.styl:

boxShadow = 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.07)

:export
  boxShadow boxShadow
```

How can I access it in another file such as:

```
// otherFile.js

import variables from '@/styles/variables.styl'

export function sample () {
  console.log(variables) // returns :export { boxShadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);}
  console.log(variables.boxShadow) // returns undefined
}
```

How can I access the value of `variables.boxShadow` in another javascript file?

Comment: seems like you missing .styl parser, your js imports it like a text instead of object

Comment: Thanks @MedetTleukabiluly, any idea how to fix this? Thank you.